# What is "git team-fetch" command do in git?

Tags: git

I am bit confuse what git team-fetch do in forking git?
I have seen command like this somewhere.

Is this command fetching branch1 code into NewBranch?

> git team-fetch xyz branch1:NewBranch

Comment: What version of `git` are you using? `git team-fetch` is not a valid command, as far as I can tell. Perhaps it's an alias on your machine? -- You can use `git config --get-regexp ^alias\.` to display all aliases.

Comment: I am using v2.6.2 and I trying to fire git config --get-regexp ^alias\.   it showing me  error: wrong number of arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your ~/bin folder, there is a script called "git-team-fetch". I took it directly from the documentation there:

```
Git enhancement - Fetch branches from other team members repositories
This script extracts the current URL from origin and tries to find
the one mapped to a user. e.g. if the user enters for an application repo:
     git team-fetch user mybranch
the real git command would look like:
     git fetch git@giturl/$application.git mybranch
```

Comment: Where did this command come from?  Is this some bizarre expansion pack?

Comment: It is project specific and i am working on the same platform than sarvesh ;) So this is no question which should be asked on stackoverflow, it should be asked in the specific chat rooms ;)